# Lower bounds for minimum variance estimators in limited space

Tags: reference-request, lower-bounds, st.statistics

[Cramer-Rao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound),  [Rao-Blackwell and Lehmann-Scheffé](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69398/whats-the-difference-between-rao-blackwell-theorem-and-lehmann-scheffe-theorem), all give you ways to prove that a statistical  estimator has the lowest variance possible. Is there any CS related work on the minimum variance estimator with limited space?  In other words, a variance/space tradeoff theorem.